# Пропадает соединение после подключения USB-модема

Tags: ubuntu

Девайс: Мегафон модем  `Huawei E1550`.Соединение часто пропадает (случается как полное отключение модема, так и просто отсутствие пинга) примерно через 10-30 минут после подключения. Чтобы соединение восстановить, требуется вытащить модем и снова подключить.

Под виндой всё работает отлично.

Подключаюсь через изкоробочную тулзу (nm, кажется).

Нашел команды для переключения режимов: `AT^U2DIAG=0`

Но куда их вставлять, не имею понятия.

Comment: > Нагуглил команды для переключения режимов: AT^U2DIAG=0Это Вам не нужно, смотрите в сторону энергосбережения. У Вас USB "ложится спать"

Comment: Всё оказалось проще. Снёс MobilePartner и всё заработало без отключений. Видимо проблема была в это кривом драйвере.

Answer (score 1):

- [Установка usb_modeswitch. Настройка 3G модема](http://archlinux.org.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=6508)
- [Настройка usb_modeswitch для подключения 3g модема](http://dergyury.wordpress.com/2011/10/25/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-usb_modeswitch-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-3g-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0/)